# Trying to convert my python code into an .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: pycharm, pyinstaller

I have been trying to convert the code into a .exe, but I keep `errno13` I used `Pyinstaller` and I have checked my permissions already. I have tried using the administrator to run, but still got `errno13.` Then I tried restarting my computer, and I also tried turning off the antivirus but nothing worked.

Any idea of what I can do to solve thisÉ

Comment: Hi there -- please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).